# Unit Testing Smarty Templates

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, smarty

I use Smarty Templates and I was just curious to know if there is any type of testing mechanism I can have on it. The number of different templates files are increasing and so is the complexity. Ideally I would love to test the final output HTML that comes to make sure templates / conditions / variables used in Smarty are working as expected. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The question is not specifically about smarty, but about program output testing. Perform controller action and test (with any tool you like) if output fits the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Smarty's [`fetch()`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.fetch.tpl) function. Below is a loose example/pseudo code.

**Template to be tested**

```
{* foo.tpl *}
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>{$hi}</body>
</html>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<!-- foo.html -->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>Hello World!</body>
</html>
```

**TestCase class**

```
class FooTemplateTestCase extends TestCase {

    protected $_view;

    public function setup(){
        $this->_view = new Smarty();
        // setup smarty options, caching, etc
    }

    public function test(){
        $this->_view->assign('hi', 'Hello World!');

        $output = $this->_view->fetch('foo.tpl');
        $expected_output = file_get_contents('foo.html');

        $this->assertEquals($expected_output, $output);
    }

}
```